# Why I need to take transpose to plot a surface correctly?

Tags: matlab, 3d, surface

Suppose C is a matrix which I need to plot with respect to two parameters parameter1 and parameter2.C is a function of parameter1 and parameter2, so I run the following loop and store value of C as function of two parameters in a matrix C

```
i_1=0;
for parameter1=1:9
i_1=i_1+1; j_1=0;
for parameter2=2:6
j_1=j_1+1;
C(j_1,i_1)=f(parameter1, parameter2);
end
end
i=1:9;
j=2:6;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(i,j);
c=surf(X,Y,C.');
```

My issue is, **why I need to transpose C here to get proper plotting? beacause when I don't I get opposite results. Is it because rows are treated as Y axis and columns as X axis?**

**How to proceed for scatter3 if I have C as a function of three variables, how should I proceed then as now C can't be transposed?**

Comment: To use surf X,Y, C should be of same dimension....

Comment: But I want to know if this is the loop then which axis will be x and which will be Y especially when all have same size , or the case when more than two axis are there.

Answer (score 1):

Okay..if your confused...whether to transpose or not....you put a if condition and go ahead to *surf*

```
i=1:9;
j=2:6;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(i,j);
C1 = zeros(length(i),length(j)) ;

for parameter1=1:9
    for parameter2=2:6
        C1(parameter1,parameter2-1)= rand ;%f(parameter1, parameter2);
    end
end


if ~isequal(size(X),size(C1)) ;
    c=surf(X,Y,C1');
else
    c=surf(X,Y,C1);
end
```

Comment: Also note that.....you need to use X,Y to surf.....straight away you can use _surf_ with your C data..it plots the surface w.r.t to it's indices....